# Room - SELECT query, get or default

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

In SQL Brite, there's a method `mapToOneOrDefault`. Is there a similar thing in Room?

Say for Model

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(@PrimaryKey val name: String)
```

and Dao

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT FROM users where name = :name")
    fun getUserByName(name: String): Flowable<User>
}
```

Not the stream returns nothing for `getUserByName("John")` if there's no `John` in DataBase. Is there a way to get a default value, say `User("")`?

Comment: Hi Sourabh, can you help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171018/css-animation-transition

Comment: Hi Sourabh, please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171018/css-animation-transition I think you're great with CSS animation.

Comment: Sorry I don't do CSS anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Not the stream returns nothing for getUserByName("John") if there's no
>   John in DataBase. Is there a way to get a default value, say User("")

There is no default mechanism.

You could change from `Flowable<User>` to `Flowable<List<User>>`.  In case of no user you will get an empty list back. You can use a `map` to check and return a default value or `filter`+`switchIfEmpty`.

Or you  could change from  `Flowable` to `Single`. With `Single`, in case of no rows, matching your query, `onError` will be triggered. You can then implement `onErrorReturn` or `onErrorResumeNext` to return a default value

Comment: Like with the other answer, this will end the stream after one value, I need it to remain open for any database updates

Comment: then, instead of `Flowable<User>` use `Flowable<List<User>>`. In case of no user you will get an empty list. You can use a map to check and decide or fiter+switchIfEmpty

Comment: That seems like a reasonable thing to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Maybe` instead of the `Flowable` in this case.

> Maybe: Conceptually, it is a union of Single and Completable providing the means to capture an emission pattern where there could be 0 or 1 item or an error signaled by some reactive source.

You can then use the operator `defaultIfEmpty` to map to a new object if the query didn't return a value.

[Reference](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)

Comment: But this will end the stream after one value, I need it to remain open for any database updates

Comment: I agree on what @Blackbelt said on that point to keep the stream up and running.