# CSS animation transition

Tags: html, css, animation

I have some problem with my animation transition time logic in my css. I have 3 images which have to slideshow. I want to change the image from image1 to image2 in 15 seconds and form image2 to image3 in 15 seconds and the go back from image 3 to image 1 in 30 seconds. I don't know how to do that with my css animation timing logic.

This is my code in html :

```
<ul>
  <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://img2.netcarshow.com/Ford-GT90_Concept_1995_800x600_wallpaper_01.jpg"></li>
  <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://img2.netcarshow.com/Mercedes-Benz-SLR_McLaren_2004_800x600_wallpaper_02.jpg"></li>
  <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://img2.netcarshow.com/Porsche-911_Carrera_4S_2002_800x600_wallpaper_0d.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

And this is my css :

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  animation: xfade 15s 4s infinite;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation: xfade 15s 8s infinite;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  animation: xfade 15s 12s infinite;
}

@keyframes xfade{
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

I create the jsfidle so everybody can make some test in this case. https://jsfiddle.net/ag0hLhnj/1/

Comment: You've abandoned this and the other identical question you've posted on SO. Please review both answers.

Comment: Why the downvote @Niloct? I'm happy to delete the answer, but having put a fair bit of thought & research into I'd like to know why you object.

Comment: Because it's possible to solve this with only css! Check my answer in the other question.

Comment: @Niloct That's sweet, thanks. I've ran your snippet for a while now & it seems to be hanging on the last slide. Does it actually continue indefinitely? I couldn't figure out how to get it to loop infinitely & keep the timing, which is why I resorted to js.

Comment: ok! The OP wanted it to stay in the 3rd image after 2 loops. You can alter the `animation-iteration-count` where it is `2` (and also in the inline form for the other rule), to `infinite`.

Comment: And you would not need the `show` animation.

Comment: Doesn't the animation delay happen once, at the beginning of the infinite-loop? The crossfade would get garbled on subsequent loops. Either way, you've perked my interest & I'll definitely dig into this deeper when time allows. Thanks for the chat!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159535/discussion-between-niloct-and-admcfajn).

Answer (score 1):

Infinite animations can't have a delay between cycles. Which means the only way to delay the timing is by buffering it within the animation (making the later animations longer and having a delay built into the animation itself).

While this is technically doable with css, it's not going to scale well. That said, there's an excellent example of just that on one of your other questions: [CSS Animation Delay and Keyframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193878/css-animation-delay-and-keyframe/47362187#answer-47362187)

Instead, you may want to control the loop with jquery.

```js
(function($){ // Closure to avoid jQuery conflicts
$(window).load(function() { //start after HTML, images have loaded

var itemInterval = 2500;

var InfiniteRotator =
{
  init: function()
  {
    var initialFadeIn = 0; //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)

    var fadeTime = 2500; //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
    var numberOfItems = 3; //count number of items
    var currentItem = 0; //set current item

    //show first item
    $('ul li').eq(currentItem).addClass('current-item'); // Can Add a Class With CSS Rules
    // $('ul li').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime); // Or Can Fade-in using jQuery

    //loop through the items
    var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){

      if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
        currentItem = 0;
      }else{
        currentItem++;
      }

      $('ul li').removeClass('current-item');
      $('ul li').eq(currentItem).addClass('current-item');

    }, itemInterval);
  }
};

InfiniteRotator.init();

});       
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}

li.current-item {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<ul>
  <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://img2.netcarshow.com/Ford-GT90_Concept_1995_800x600_wallpaper_01.jpg"></li>
  <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://img2.netcarshow.com/Mercedes-Benz-SLR_McLaren_2004_800x600_wallpaper_02.jpg"></li>
  <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://img2.netcarshow.com/Porsche-911_Carrera_4S_2002_800x600_wallpaper_0d.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really understand with this. Could you give me some code which made the image transition in 15 sec and when it go back to first image it will in 30 sec ?

Comment: My code above gives me the animation slideshow but it change in 4 seconds and I can't make it in 15 seconds.

Comment: @Antonio I don't think it's possible to do what you want to do that way.

Comment: Could you give me some complete sample so I can possible to do that ?

Comment: Edited my answer. You'll be able to get the css-transitions figured out on your own, eh?