# CSS Animation Delay and Keyframe

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with animation delay on CSS Animation. I have 3 images and I want to make it slideshow. The illustrations is, image 1 to image 2 takes 15 seconds to change and image 2 to image 3 takes 15 seconds to change and image 3 back to image 1 it takes 30 seconds, after the first loop, I want to make the slideshow end in image 3 so image 1 to image 2 still 15 seconds and image 2 to image 3 still 15 seconds and when image 3 load it no need to back to image 1. I tried this code but it gives me 15 seconds delay to all images. This is my code :

```css
ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    li {
      position: absolute;
      opacity:0;
    }
    
    li {
      animation: xfade 45s  infinite;
    }
    li:nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay:15s;
    }
    li:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay:30s;
    }
    
    @keyframes xfade{ 
      3%{opacity:1}
      33% {opacity:1;}
      36%{opacity:0}
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports" alt="pic1"></li>
      <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/people" alt="pic2"></li>
      <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport" alt="pic3"></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to make delay in my animation according the illustrations above. Anyone could help me solve this problem ? Thank you before.

Comment: here is the best solution but for that, you have to use gsap animation bcoz CSS animation is not as we want. So for best result, you must use gsap animation it's so easy. Here is the live URL https://greensock.com/gsap

Comment: @HardenRahul Thanks for your advise. But, GSAP used javascript and I can't used javascript because my client don't want to used javascript.

Comment: then you can use this example from code pen here is the URL: https://codepen.io/daysahead/pen/mJqBge

Comment: @Antonio check my solution too.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that using GreenSock is better if you want animation with specific scenario like this.

Here is the closest I can get with HTML and CSS, I also need to duplicate the `<li>` to fit your scenario.

```css
ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    li {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    li:nth-child(6) {
      /*The last item always on the top, direction will goes from last to first*/
      animation: xfade 15s;
    }
    li:nth-child(5) {
      /*Put animation length double the delay (in this case delay is the actual animation length)*/
      animation: xfade 30s 15s;
    }
    li:nth-child(4) {
      animation: xfade 30s 15s;
    }
    li:nth-child(3) {
      animation: xfade 30s 15s;
    }
    li:nth-child(2) {
      animation: xfade 30s 15s;
    }
    li:nth-child(1) {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    @keyframes xfade{ 
      0%{opacity:0}
      33% {opacity:1;}
      100%{opacity:0}
    }
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>1<img width="500" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports" alt="pic1"></li>
      <li>2<img width="500" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/people" alt="pic2"></li>
      <li>3<img width="500" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport" alt="pic3"></li>

      <!-- Duplicate -->
      <li>4<img width="500" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports" alt="pic1"></li>
      <li>5<img width="500" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/people" alt="pic2"></li>
      <li>6<img width="500" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport" alt="pic3"></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: How about the delay ? Could you make it in 15 secs 15 secs and 30 secs ?

Comment: Yup, just update the `nth-child(4)` to `xfade 45s 30s` and you are good to go. I think its better for you to modify the xfade keyframe percentage to make it smoother.

Comment: From `animation: xfade 30s 15s;` there is 30s and 15s. Could you explain to me what is that mean of 30s and 15s is ?

Comment: The first number is animation length, and the second number is animation delay. The actual animation not just fading out (opacity 1 -> 0) but fade in out (opacity 0 -> 1 -> 0). This makes the animation needs to start before it actually shows up so that when it shows up to the user, it already has `opacity: 1`. 

With this logic, your scenario of 'animation length' become the 'animation delay'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that gave real food for thought :)

I had to apply 2 animations for opacity change: `xfade-25pct` and `xfade-50pct`. Both play only 2 times, fading out briefly after 25% and 50% of the animation. And an additional `show` animation to make the 3rd image stick after 2 animation loops, with the necessary rule `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`.

The trick to opacity is this: you have to split the animation in 4 quarters. If you want you can change the total animation duration from `60s` to a multiple of 4, and adjust the delays. The 3rd animation delay is the double of the 2nd one.

```
----#----#----#----#----#----#----#----#----#----#
1st animation      | 1st animation     |
--------------------------------------------------
15s | 2nd animation     | 2nd animation     |
--------------------------------------------------
30s      | 3rd animation     |   3rd animation   |
----#----#----#----#----#----#----#----#----#----#
```

Feel free to ask. Hope this helps you.

```js
var s = 0,
  c = 1;
/* Code for displaying timer */
window.setInterval(function() {
  s++;
  document.querySelector('DIV').innerHTML = s;
  if (s == 15 && c <= 2 || s == 30) {
    if (s == 30) {
      c = 1;
    } else {
      c++;
    }
    s = 0;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

li {
  animation: xfade-25pct 60s 2;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 30s, 120s;
  animation-name: xfade-50pct, show;
  animation-duration: 60s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2, 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes xfade-25pct {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2%,
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  27% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes xfade-50pct {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2%,
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  52% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<DIV></DIV>
<ul>
  <li><img width="500" height="500" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/pelican_500.jpg" alt="pic1"></li>
  <li><img width="500" height="500" src="http://whc.unesco.org/uploads/thumbs/news_920-500-500-20151015155516.jpg" alt="pic2"></li>
  <li><img width="500" height="500" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/4c/17/65/4c176537aee906de294138c3bac5b8f5--merry-christmas-love-coffee-aroma.jpg" alt="pic3"></li>
</ul>
```